# WPF DataGridRow fire event on MouseOver

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Is there an event I can use when a user puts their mouse cursor over a row? Basically I need to change the tooltip of the row when the cursor changes row

I have something like this so far

```
 <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
         <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                         Value="True">
               <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseMove" Handler="MouseMoveEvent"></EventSetter>
            </Trigger>
         </Style.Triggers> 
 </Style>
```

But it doesn't quite work.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't put `EventSetter` inside a normal `Trigger`. Looks like `EventSetter` can just be used inside `Style.Setters` (not `Trigger.Setters`), see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.eventsetter.aspx), look at the last line in the **Remarks** section.

In this case I don't think you need to change the handler dynamically, just hook the events ***once***. So put the `EventSetter` inside `Style.Setters`. Also the best event for your purpose is `MouseEnter`, not `PreviewMouseMove`:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
   <EventSetter Event="MouseEnter" Handler="Row_MouseEnter"/>
</Style>
```

**Code behind**:

```
private void Row_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e){
   //put your code here to set the ToolTip for each row
   //Here I just set the ToolTip to the index of the row
   var row = e.Source as DataGridRow;
   row.ToolTip = row.GetIndex().ToString();
}
```

Another solution is naming your `DataGrid` so that we can refer it in code behind. Then add handler for the event `LoadingRow`. There you can set the ToolTip for each row:

```
//inside the Window constructor after IntializeComponent()
dataGrid1.LoadingRow += (s,e) => {
    e.Row.Tooltip = e.Row.GetIndex().ToString(); 
};
```

Also you should consider using Binding to set the ToolTip. That way you need an appropriate ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to Use EventTriggers.
You'll need capture MouseEnter and MouseLeave events.

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
   ...
</EventTrigger>
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
   ...
</EventTrigger>
```